# Network boot (PXE) Ubuntu unable to pass downloading archive

Tags: ubuntu, networking, pxe, netboot

Okay, I've created DHCP server with [Serva](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/), booted Ubuntu 12 installer on other laptop in option "Network boot" and everything's ok (Language, keyboard, connection and choosing mirror) untill downloading archive from mirrors.

After I choose mirror eg. Bosnia and Herzegovina (or whatever else) and press ENTER, window containing title "**Downloading archive files...**" appears and the percent bar is there with **0 %** and then, that window dissapears and only blue screen with white bar on bottom appears.  (I can access BusyBox terminal by pressing ALT + 2)

Picture (Live):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NuiZt9vs.jpg]
[Click to open larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoTpH.jpg)

What can be problem? I think internet connection works because it pass network configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by waiting about an hour, didn't know. So anyone who experience this, just wait.

Comment: That's not normal; you might have a very slow connection to the repository site...